# Unable to establish connection with R session

Tags: r

When running a simple glm in R the "Unable to establish connection with R session" error occurs, after the second glm i run. I have tried ways to solve this issue, like reinstalling R and R- 
Studio, this has not helped at all. 
This has happend for the last three days, always when running the second glm. It is a real pain.

Comment: try running this in the terminal; if the problem is specific to RStudio, you might check https://community.rstudio.com/ for more RStudio-specific help

Comment: I will try this asap, thank you.

Comment: @MichaelChirico this did not solve the problem, i have now observed that the problem occurs immediately after not being able to allocate a vector of a certain size.

Comment: well, that's progress anyway!